# How did Minori and co. get back to Akiba at the end of S2E21?

Tags: log-horizon

Towards the end of season 2, episode 21 of Log Horizon, as Minori and the rest of the gang are walking home after getting some wyvern skins, they run into Nyanta, who "happens" to be flying by on a griffon. In the next scene, everybody is back in Akiba.

But how did they get back? Don't griffons only have a capacity of 2 riders? Did Nyanta make multiple trips, maybe?

Comment: Maybe Nyanta only went there to tell them they did good, and it was time to go home, and they all used Call of Home to get back to Akiba.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the skill lists on the Log Horizon Wikia I could not find another skill that would allow them to fast travel back to Akihabara but according to the Adventurers abilities page they can use Call of Home to return ref([Adventurer Abilities](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Adventurer)). So it would make sense that they either used Call of Home or just traveled back on foot with a time lapse that wasn't noted. ref([Skills](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Skills))